# For loop for displaying each character of string | C++

Tags: c++, compilation

I want to know how can I control string and get characters from string. 
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int mainMenu();

int main() {
    mainMenu();
}

int mainMenu(){
    string introText = "Welcome... Let me know your name!";
    cout << "\t\t\t";
    for (int i = 0; i <= introText.length(); i++){
        unsigned controller = i + 1;
        cout <<introText.substr(i,controller);
    }
}
```

This Outputs following:

```
    Wellcocomeome..me... e... Le... Let .. Let me. Let me k Let me knoLet me know et me know yot me know your me know your nme know your name know your name! know your name!know your name!now your name!ow your name!w your name! your name!your name!our name!ur name!r name! name!name!ame!me!e!!
```

What is the right direction to go toward? How can I solve this?

Comment: Why a substr? Why not just use introText[i].

Comment: can you tell us the output you are expecting?

Comment: Maybe you are confused about the fact that `substr`'s second parameter is the number of characters to include in the substring and *not* the upper index until the substring is taken. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: substr method in C/C++ is different from substring in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::basic_string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) is used to extract part of a string. If you want to print each char of the string, you can just use [`std::basic_string::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) or [`std::basic_string::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at):

```
for (int i = 0; i < introText.length(); i++){
    cout <<introText[i]; // or cout <<introText.at(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int mainMenu();

int main() {
    mainMenu();
}

int mainMenu(){
    string introText = "Welcome... Let me know your name!";
    cout << "\t\t\t";
    for (int i = 0; i < introText.length(); i++){
        //unsigned controller = i + 1;
        //cout <<introText.substr(i,controller);
        cout << introText[i];
    }
        cout << endl;
}
```

This outputs

```
                Welcome... Let me know your name!
```

Just use `introText[i]`

Answer (score 0):

```
int mainMenu(){
string introText = "Welcome... Let me know your name!";
cout << "\t\t\t";
for (int i = 0; i < introText.length(); i++){

    cout << introText[i];
}
    cout << endl;
```

}